# 50% height Centered background-image and the remaining space a background-color

Tags: html, css

I want to have a background where the top 50% of the users heights size, is a background-image there is centered so it fits 100% width and 50% height. The remaining 50% or more (If content is more then 100% height) should be a background color.

Example:
[image: Example]

This is what i have so far:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: url('http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-black-and-white/wallpaper-black-and-white-7.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#content{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum Dolar
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7devux/6/

I know this is not right. First of all, the image isn't centered, and i have sat the height of html + body to 100% which won't work if content exceeds the 100% of the users browser height. Also i have sat #wrapper to 50% in height, which isn't correct either, it should only apply to the background-image.

How would (and should) I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but considering your approach here, this is the easiest one:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-black-and-white/wallpaper-black-and-white-7.jpg') no-repeat center 240%, #858585;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

#content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum Dolar
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Once more, this is made to fit your approach, there are a few other ways you can tackle this.

All properties are just made-up so they can fit your aim. You can see for example a 250% Y offset for the background-image. You will have to create an image that fits nicely at the top of the backdrop in this case, so you won't need a negative offset.

Comment: What if content exceeds 100% height? You have also sat html + body to 100%. And even content is limited to 60%, this is not what i look for

Comment: I am not sure I understand you fully. You can't have percentage value of nothing (meaning you must have a parent value). The 900px height that I've set is just for display reasons. Your content will span across and will expand it.

Answer (score 1):

here is the updated code. i just updated your css

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green url('http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-black-and-white/wallpaper-black-and-white-7.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 40%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 40%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 40%;
  background-size: 100% 40%;
  background-position: top center;
}
#content{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum Dolar
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```