# How can I make a flex container background: top-half to be an image and bottom half to be a background-color?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container and I want this container to have as a background-image/color to be 50%/50% (Top/bottom). This is a template therefor **I do not know the container height in advance** and I want the container to wrap the elements inside it whatever their height is.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025364/50-height-centered-background-image-and-the-remaining-space-a-background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple background like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background:
   url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) top/100% 50% no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
 height:100vh;
}
```

or simply like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background:
   url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) top/100% 50% no-repeat,
   red;
 height:100vh;
}
```

Also like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background:
   linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat,
   url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover no-repeat;
 height:100vh;
}
```